# CSS, HTML - Color change of HR element by button:active

Tags: html, css

I have 4 buttons with a horizontal line underneath for which i used a HR element. When i click the buttons they turn red. Is it possible that i make the line underneath turn red as well when i click any of the buttons?

```
button.nav-buttons {
  width: 130px;
  border: 0.5px solid;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.nav-buttons:hover {
  border-color: white;
}

button.nav-buttons:active {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#hr-nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the general sibling combinator `~`:

```
button.nav-buttons:active~#hr-nav { border-color: red; }
```

For that to work, the `button` elements and the `hr` element need to have the same parent element.

If that is not the case, please add the relevant HTML structure to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use adjacent sibling selector (+). with the "+" selector you can select an element that is directly after another element. `button.nav-buttons:active + hr { border-color: red;}`

```css
button.nav-buttons {
width: 130px;
border: 0.5px solid;
xxx_background-color: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
color: white;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 20px;}


button.nav-buttons:hover {
border-color: white;}

button.nav-buttons:active {
color: red;
border: 1px solid red;}

button.nav-buttons:active + hr { border-color: red;}

#hr-nav {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid white;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="parent">
  <button class="nav-buttons">x</button>
  <hr/>  
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <button class="nav-buttons">x</button>
  <hr/>  
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#nav-bar-outer { width: 100%; }

#nav-bar { margin: auto; width: 55%;}

a.nav-buttons {
width: 500px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 2px 20px;
padding: 0px 25px;
background-color: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
color: black;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none; }

a.nav-buttons:hover { border-color: white; }

a.nav-buttons:active { border-color: red; color: red; }

a.nav-buttons:active~#hr-nav { border-color: red; }
</style>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div id="nav-bar-outer"><div id="nav-bar"><center>
        <a class="nav-buttons" href="">1</a>
        <a class="nav-buttons" href="">2</a>
        <a class="nav-buttons" href="">3</a>
        <a class="nav-buttons" href="">4</a>
        <hr id="hr-nav"></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).